# vim c++ clang_complete doesn't work for std::cin.get()

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion, filetype-c++, plugin-clang-complete

I'm using vim to do c++ projects on Mac OS X.

To auto complete, I use this plugin: [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete)

For most of cases, such as members of user-defined classes, members of namespaces, it works very well.
For example, when I type `std::`, many things such as `cout`, `cin` will popup.

However, when I type `std::cin.`, or `std::string str; str.` nothing popups and I got an error:

> Pattern not found

It seems that user-defined classes' members can popup automatically whereas C++ Library stuff's members can't. I don't know why.

Here is my .vimrc file:
[image]